# Exclude only one activity from stack of recents

Tags: android, android-recents

I've the following problem: When I exclude from stack of recents through `AndroidManifest.xml` in only one activity, all my activities are excluded from recents.

How can I exclude from the stack of recents only one of these activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "*remove*" (*exclude*) the Activity from the recents stack —*I think is what you want*— you can add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` into the Activity definition (`AndroidManifest.xml`) as follow:

```
<activity
  android:name=".ActivityWithoutRecents"
  android:label="@string/WithoutRecents"
  android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

For me is the easiest way to do that (*and the cleanest*). This should work, hiding from the pile of recents the specified activity.